# Rotating sphere - time correlation

Tags: geometry

Consider a sphere with unit radius and the center at the origin $O$. We mark a reference point $X$ on the surface of the sphere. At each instant, the sphere rotates about a random axis by an angle $\phi$. In that case, what will be the time correlation function of the vector $\vec{OX}$? i.e. what is

$$\vec{OX}(0)\cdot \vec{OX}(t)?$$

Edit: $\phi$ is typically very small and not $2\pi$.
If the point $X$ was to displace (on the surface of the sphere) by a small distance (Brownian motion or random walk on a sphere) the time correlation is given by $\exp(-t)$.

Comment: Is phi constant?  Could it be $2\pi$

Comment: If you want an exact result, look into convolution on the sphere using spherical harmonics.